# Verification Token or Signing Secret for AWS Lex to Slack connector?

Tags: slack-api, amazon-lex

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/slack-step-3.html) for a slack connector for Lex say to use the Verification Token.

The slack API says that Verification Tokens are deprecated.

Should we all be using the Signing Secret for LexV2 at this point?